# How can I get sliced documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have many documents like this:

[image]

How can I get, say, 11 documents without everything expect `content.headline`, `content.description`, `content.tags` and `id` fields via `_id`.

Simply put I have array of `_id` and I want to get news fields via this array.

Array example:

```js
[
  6002baa15e0b210f9ccd3060,
  6002baa25e0b210f9ccd3062,
  6002ba9e5e0b210f9ccd305c,
  6002baa05e0b210f9ccd305f,
  6002ba9f5e0b210f9ccd305d,
  6002ba9e5e0b210f9ccd305b,
  6002baa15e0b210f9ccd3061,
  6002ba9c5e0b210f9ccd3059,
  6002ba8d5e0b210f9ccd3058,
  6002ba9d5e0b210f9ccd305a,
  6002baa05e0b210f9ccd305e
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the same `dot` notation as it is object.

You do normal find with project and limit.

```
db.coll.find({}, 
{
"content.headline":1,
"another_field":1
}
 ).limit(11)
```